# MySQL 5.7 - getting latest entry(s) from specific combination of columns

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group, mysql-5.7

Hello dear MySQL users!

i try to solf this since a while but everything i tried does not seem to work.
I'm sorry if somewhere is already an answer for that but i know know how to search for.

Its not so easy to explain in words so i use this table (called `tbl` ) to explain it:

| ID | SerNo | TypeOfChange | InfoAboutChange | TimestampOfChange |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Name | DN01 | 2020/12/01 |
| 2 | 1 | IPAddress | 192.168.1.1 | 2020/12/01 |
| 3 | 1 | Name | DNX1 | 2020/12/02 |
| 4 | 2 | Name | DN02 | 2020/12/04 |
| 5 | 2 | IPAddress | 192.168.1.2 | 2020/12/04 |
| 6 | 1 | Name | DNC1 | 2020/12/05 |

Now i want to get the *latest* state of *each* SerNo. It should look like this:

| ID | SerNo | TypeOfChange | InfoAboutChange | TimestampOfChange |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | IPAddress | 192.168.1.1 | 2020/12/01 |
| 6 | 1 | Name | DNC1 | 2020/12/05 |
| 4 | 2 | Name | DN02 | 2020/12/04 |
| 5 | 2 | IPAddress | 192.168.1.2 | 2020/12/04 |

i found out how to get the latest entry of each `TypeofChange` but its the very latest change ignoring the SerNo of a device:

`select TypeOfChange, max(TimestampOfChange) from tbl group by TypeOfChange`

i thing i need a combination of **grouping SerNo** and after that finding all **typeofchange**, **group them** and finding the latest version with **max()**

but i absolutely have no clue how to to that.

Thank you and stay healthy!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: What defines the device is not clear.

Comment: Ah sorry, you are right, "device" is "SerNo". I changed that in the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where timestampofchange = (
    select max(t1.timestampofchange)
    from mytable t1
    where t1.typeofchange = t.typeofchange and t1.erno = t.serno
)
```

Comment: wow... yes, that works like a charm. It's that simple that i can only scratch my head and say to myself "Why did you tried all these INNER JOIN things all the time. Thank you!